# Proving a relationship between the infimums of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded, real-valued functions defined on $[a,b]$. Define
>   \begin{align*}
> A &= \{f(x_1)+g(x_2) : x_1,x_2\in[a,b]\},\\
> B &= \{f(x)+g(x) : x\in[a,b]\}.
> \end{align*}
>   How are inf$A$ and inf$B$ related? Prove your answer.

My attempted solution is as follows:

$\mbox{inf}A=\mbox{min}f+\mbox{min}g\geq\mbox{min}(f+g)=\mbox{inf}B$.

I'm not entirely convinced that this is correct, and even if it is, I'm unsure of how to prove it.

Comment: *Why* do you think that.  And why do you think that $\min f$ and $\min g$ exist?

Comment: One obvious thing to note:  $B \subset A$.

Comment: @fleablood You're right, I assumed a hypothesis that we don't have. Since we don't know that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, the extreme value theorem doesn't apply, meaning the minimums might not exist.

Comment: @fleablood Certainly $B\subseteq A$, so actually it must be the case that $\mbox{inf}B\geq\mbox{inf}A$

Comment: @fleablood With equality only when $f=g$ is a constant function. So I guess that's the entire proof?

Comment: I'm not sure how much it helps, but you can talk about $\inf{f}$ and $\inf{g}$ instead of $\min{f}$ and $\min{g}$.

Comment: Equality can happen without $f = g$ and without either being constant.  Assuming for the sake of simplicity that each function has a minimum, equality happens iff there is a single point $x$ where both functions achieve their minimums at once.  (In general, the same condition applies in an approximate sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rigourous proof :

You have $B\subseteq A$.

By definition, $\forall x\in A, x\geq \inf(A)$ and $\forall x\in B, x\geq \inf(B)$.

($\inf(A)$ and $\inf(B)$ exist because f and g are bounded on $[a,b]$)

Let $b\in B$.

Since $B\subset A$, $b\in A$.

Consequently, by the above definition, $b\geq \inf(A)$.

So now we know that $\forall b \in B, b\geq \inf(A)$.

So $\inf(A)\in\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R} |\forall b \in B, b\geq x\rbrace$.

Or, by definition, $\inf(B)=\max\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R} |\forall b \in B, b\geq x\rbrace$.

So by definition of the max function, $\inf(A)\leq\inf(B)$.